# Perl: Creating script that removes a second half of any word with an even number of letters

Tags: perl, scripting, conditional-statements

Sorry for not adding what I've done before. I need to write a script that takes a text file, searches for words with even number of letters and removes the second half of those words. Afterwards I need it to copy the whole text to a new file with those changed words exactly where they were etc. etc.
I'm really stuck at finding how I do this half-removing script part.

For example, this text

*A bunch of new people started at work and we use a lot of Perl in our department*

should look like that at the end:

*A bunch o new peo started a wo and w use a lot o Pe i our depar*

All my THANKS to **ikegami**

What I have so far:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use vars qw($filecontent);

    my $file1 = "File1.txt";

    open(FILE1, $file1) || die "couldn't open the file!";

    open(FILE2, '>>File1.half') || die "couldn't open the file!";

    while($filecontent = <FILE1>){

    chomp($filecontent);

    print FILE2 $filecontent."\n";

    }

    close(FILE1);
    close(FILE2);

    open(FILE2, '>>File1.half') || die "couldn't open the file!";

    while ( <FILE2> ) {
        $_ =~ s/ \b(\w+)\b / length($1) % 2 ? $1 : substr($1, 0, length($1)/2) /eg;

        print FILE2 $_;
    }

    close(FILE2);
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at pp1.pl line 27.

Number found where operator expected at pp1.pl line 27, near "s/ \b(\w+)\b / length($1) % 2 ? $1 : substr($1, 0, length($1)/2"

syntax error at pp1.pl line 27, near "s/ \b(\w+)\b / length($1) % 2 ? $1 : substr($1, 0, length($1)/2"
Execution of pp1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: Please show us some code you've already attempted.

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment. Have you tried anything. Do you know any Perl? You've got to demonstrate [a minimal understanding of the problem and your attempts at solutions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). People here are usually eager to help, but this isn't a _write my code for me site_.

Answer (score 1):

```
s/\b(\w+)\b/ length($1) % 2 ? $1 : substr($1, 0, length($1)/2) /eg;
```

Comment: +1 for this answer. If he succeeds in figuring out *why* your code works, he'll have learned more than by solving the original question himself.